# Cordova + Angular: How to test?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, tdd, karma-runner, protractor

I've just recently started fooling around with Cordova for a mobile App. For now the code base is quite small. I've also used AngularJS to drive my javascript. Now that I have reached a stable state, I would like to investigate ways to unit test the code I just wrote. Thing is, I'm not finding any useful resource for the pair. Angular suggests either Karma (unit) or Protractor (scenarios), but I'm finding quite hard to bootstrap them both with a Cordova App, since this is not supposed to run inside the browser, but within some kind of container where cordova can be loaded. Are there already some good test-driven approaches in the open source market regarding test driven development of hybrid apps?

Comment: What I've donz so far is making the code usable without cordova (that's imply a lot of if window.cordova) but you can test it with karma and developing on the web witch can be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

I think that correct approach would be to have `cordova.mocks.js` included in tests that will mock out cordova dependencies. And then unittest as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "phonegap server" even if you're using cordova, also you can run on the device with `cordova run <platform> --device`.

You can track issues on the CLI output of both methods.

Comment: The OP asked about cordova, which is the opensource project which phonegap is based on.

The `phonegap server` command would be `cordova serve` without having to rely on the on phonegap.

Also running on the device doesn't change anything as you more likely would not be able to test the hybrid app within a physical phone.
Also tracking "issues" as you say on CLI output isn't a proper way to use test-driven development, and you can't rely on it to test apps.

Comment: In any moment at my post i've said that my answer is the most right, but it fits to me and i'm sharing it, if it will works to his job or not is what will decide if my answer is right and then he'll mark my post as the answer of the topic, that's the simple and the logic way that the stackoverflow works, so, if you think that you're right and i'm not, give him a post about how to do and let him decide, but now, if you do not have any answer to him and only wants to keep saying that anyone is wrong and leave him without an answer you should go to 4chan and stay being helpful there.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way at the moment to test the parts of cordova that would call functionality from plugins.

But you could use Karma or Protractor as you would in the browser (eventually with some mocks for cordova and cordova plugins), which require some additional `if` conditionals to run the app without a physical device

Ie `if (window.cordova && cordova.plugins.thePluginExample) { /* Code that uses plugins [...] */ }`

Answer (score 0):

To help others who get here with the same question as I did...

You probably don't need to bootstrap with Cordova.  Use mocks as stand-ins.

Since Cordova attaches to `window`, you can write your app code to inject `$window` and mock cordova with with standard mocking.

Example with `mocha` / `chai`:

```js
/**
 * Test case for AngularJS module that does something when platform = 'ios'
 */
describe('platform = "ios"', function() {

  var $window;
  beforeEach('inject', inject(function(_$window_) {
    $window = _$window_;

    $window.cordova = {
      platformId: 'ios',
    }
  }));

  it('verifies cordova mock platform = "ios"', function() {
    expect($window.cordova.platformId).to.equal('ios');
  });

  it('does something', function() {
    // ...
  });

});
```